# Recurrence Rule Error 400 Bad Request - Google Api Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to create a recurrence rule with the [Google Calendar Api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents).

```
 [JAVASCRIPT - Google Client Library]
 var req = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  [...],
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL="+date.toISOString()
  ],
  [...]
 });
 req.execute();
```

The code above return 400 Bad request, because the recurrence rule is not correctly formatted.

I don't understand how to create a correct date format for the `UNTIL` field.

I've tried to use a date object and use the ISO conversion but it doesn't work either.

Anyway a single creation for the event works correctly and also a repeat with a `COUNT` field.

[FILE ON GITHUB](https://github.com/rkpasia/Calendar-Generator/blob/gh-pages/js/calendar-generator.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several rules that apply to UNTIL. First of all, it is not an ISO string but of value DATE or DATE-TIME (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5). Then you need to pay attention that the DATE value is used if the recurring event start is all-day event and vice versa. At last you need to pay attention to Timezone. The UNTIL must be in the same timezone as your start. I really recommend reading about recurrence rules in the RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3

Comment: I'm creating events that are 1hr longer. The start time and the end time are outside the recurrence property, do you think that should add these also inside the recurrence rule?

Comment: No, start and end are separate fields and should not go inside the recurrence. However, the rules that apply to DTSTART and DTEND also apply to start and end in v3.

Comment: So they automatically nested inside, the only problem is to correctly format the UNTIL property at this point.

Comment: I've added the link to the file on github, maybe it could help.

Comment: I've found in the resources linked the right date format to use inside the api request. Thanks :)